# Ubuntu 18.04 apt-get qt5-default screwed. Work-around?

Tags: qt, ubuntu, installation

I'm trying to install Qt on a new Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS build from a DVD burned
in Nov. 2018.

The common wisdom on the internet, that I successfully used in Nov. 2018, is:-

- sudo apt-get install build-essential
- sudo apt-get install qtcreator
- sudo apt-get install qt5-default

Today (2019-03-20) the qt-default install produces:-

"Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 qt5-default : Depends: qtbase5-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages"

I can only assume the package has been updated with a broken version. How do
I install the old Nov. 2018 version? https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic-updates/qt-default etc doesn't appear to list old versions.

I did let the install download updates so it might be something else that has
changed.

Or are there other work-arounds?

Comment: Is your goal to install Qt only from official packages? Do you want to do that fully offline from the DVD? You can install from Qt's online installer (from their website) in unattended mode if that helps, but I'm not sure that matches your use case

Comment: Thanks Adrien. I did install from the installer on the Qt site. More awkward than the apt-get version in its ability to find kits. My objective is easy of build and maintenance.

Comment: FWIW, this seems to be fixed in the latest 18.04 LTS release, but is now happening in the 20.04 LTS release.